# What is the formatter %@ in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

What actually %@ means when it's using by NSLog? And when we use that?

```
    NSDate* d  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1201921383];
    NSLog(@"result: %@",d);
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by `descriptionWithLocale`: if available, or `description` otherwise. Also works with `CFTypeRef` objects, returning the result of the `CFCopyDescription` function.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html